# How can I batch load 1,000 XML files and convert to JSON with Talend?

Tags: json, xml, graph-databases, talend

How can I batch load 1,000 XML files and convert to JSON with Talend? Is it possible to connect to Neo4J with Talend or maybe connect to an RDF Graph Database like Fluree?

Comment: Please only ask 1 question per post. Also, what have you already tried and what issues did you face? If you ask specific questions you are more likely to get a helpful response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following components, [tFileInputXML](https://help.talend.com/r/mjoDghHoMPI0yuyZ83a13Q/E3tQgEhQFdEfsQEMnfPGzg) and [tFileOutputJSON](https://help.talend.com/r/6DCq4OstF4OfhmRxx8dVuw/QGR78RQoCtdhY3m0o5AHaw)

I leave you a link to the documentation, look at the scenarios, they indicate how to configure each element.

I have worked with these elements, the reading of the XML works, you may have to read the file in different Inputs, it all depends on the structure of the xml.

You can also validate it using an XSD.

Regards.